# Change data from COLUMNS in to a ROW MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some data listed like the attached picture

`SELECT Code, compCode FROM KitItems`

The data is currently formatted like this:

[image]

But i want it to be transposed in to a number of columns

Like this:

[image]

Any ideas

Comment: Please read this:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I have provided the script

how it is now image
How i want it after

What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` & do the conditional aggregation :

```
select code, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then compcode end) as one,
       max(case when seq = 2 then compcode end) as two,
       . . .
       max(case when seq = 7 then compcode end) as seven
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by compcode) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
group by code;
```

Same could be achieve via dynamic `PIVOT` SQL if `code` has too many `compcode`s.